# Inserting Data into MySQL Table via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add some simple user data into a database via a webpage written in PHP, but the following code (more specifically, line three) breaks the page. Am I using the wrong MySQL function? I'm pretty sure my query is formatted correctly.

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE stats ( userAgent CHAR(20) )");

$userAgent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO stats VALUES ("$userAgent"));
```

Comment: Expand on "breaks the page". Is there an error? What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PHP error can be fixed like this (note the dot, it's used to "glue" the strings together):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO stats VALUES (".$userAgent.")");
```

Also, you should do some SQL Injection protection, the user-agent string is user-defined (there are tools to modify it), so it needs to be sanitized. Further, the user-agent is a string so you need to put it in between single quotes.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO stats VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($userAgent) . "')");
```

Another important thing would be error handling - echoing the error description is necessary to find bugs in your SQL syntax.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO stats VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($userAgent) . "')")
    or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO stats VALUES (".$userAgent.")");
```

Comment: This fixes the PHP error, but not the wrong SQL syntax and the SQL injection problem.

Comment: Downvoted due to sql injection. Sorry, but there's too much bad advice like this out there already.

Comment: So `INSERT INTO stats VALUES (Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; de; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8)` is a valid SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

Eton B. has the right answer, but please note that the code you've written will leave you at the mercy of [little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

***DON'T DO THIS***

Answer (score 0):

Are you escaping your `$userAgent` variable?

Data must be "cleaned" before going anywhere near your database.

```
<?php
// Connect
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    OR die(mysql_error());

// Clean
$userAgent = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
// Query
mysql_query("INSERT INTO stats VALUES ($userAgent)");
?>
```